# Pushing Git commits through RStudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I have started to use Git package inside [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN) . It seems to work fine for Master branch. But adding another branch, you can commit any changes through the GUI but the "push" button doesn't work. Any thoughts how this can be fixed? I can do the push through the terminal but not GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Hadley's explanation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/git.html#git-branch):

> If you try to synchronise this [new] branch to GitHub from inside RStudio,
>   you’ll notice that push and pull are disabled. To enable them,
>   you’ll need to first tell Git that your local branch has a remote
>   equivalent:
>
> `git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>` After you’ve done that
>   once, you can use the pull and push buttons as usual.